# Where is the file history backup going?

Tags: windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive

I'm confused by the backup settings interface for Windows 10. I want to create an external backup of my files and all of their versions. I think that's what I accomplished in the "Backup Settings" window:

[image: backup settings]

I tried to select my external drive to backup to:

[image: advanced backup settings]

When I then try to do a test restore, I can open up "File History", but I don't know where this history is coming from:

[image: file history]

Am I backing up my file history to my external drive or is it just a snapshot of my files at the current state? Am I also saving the file-history to my local drive? How can I figure this out?

What I want to do is backup my system, so when my device inevitably brick itself, I can plug this external drive into the new system and restore everything, including my files and maybe even my programs.

Comment: In order to determine where your file history is going, you have to look at the legacy UI, same process you used on Windows 7.  "What I want to do is backup my system," - File History isn't going to achieve this goal.

Comment: [Here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=File+History+Windows+7&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN), [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17128/windows-8-file-history), and [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/) and specifically [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/image312.png).  As I said this will restore your personal files, but it won't restore your programs, so it won't achieve your described goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is backup my system, so when my device inevitably
>   brick itself, I can plug this external drive into the new system and
>   restore everything, including my files and maybe even my programs.

File History will be unable to restore your installed programs and their settings which are located in AppData which is contained within your user's local profile directory.

> Am I backing up my file history to my external drive or is it just a
>   snapshot of my files at the current state?

You are backing up the actual file and it's a revision history of the file.

> When I then try to do a test restore, I can open up "File History",
>   but I don't know where this history is coming from

If you look on your D partition (it might be hidden) your file history is being stored there.

> Am I also saving the file-history to my local drive?

Yes, I assume the D volume is a local drive.

> What I want to do is backup my system, so when my device inevitably
>   brick itself, I can plug this external drive into the new system and
>   restore everything, including my files and maybe even my programs.

File history will nor accomplish this goal.

Comment: Removed that part of the question.